# undefined symbol: xsltGetProfileInformation while importing pyquery

Tags: python, xslt, lxml, pyquery

I'm trying to use pyquery on Python 3.8.3, and fail due to:

```
>>> import pyquery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyquery/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .pyquery import PyQuery  # NOQA
  File "/opt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: /opt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-38.so: undefined symbol: xsltGetProfileInformation
```

the OS is CoreELEC, so no "apt-get", but only "opkg install" like in OpenWRT.

tried reinstalling both lxml and pyquery, but it didn't work.
where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out eventually.
the system only has "opkg install" way of installing packages.
`python3-lxml` package was already installed, along with `libxml2`.
I had to also install `libxslt` for it to work.
so eventually the steps are:

```
opkg install python3-lxml
opkg install libxml2
opkg install libxslt
```

and now I'm able to import pyquery (which uses etree from lxml).

Answer (score 0):

I get the same bug on `OpenWrt 19.x.x` with python 3.7. But on previous versions, all works fine. So I just force removed `libxml2` and `libxslt` libraries and reinstall them from the previous branch.